# How to get the HTTP-Status from a webMethods com.wm.net.NetException?

Tags: http, exception, webmethods

How to get the HTTP-Status from a webMethods com.wm.net.NetException?

Is there a way to get the http status code from within the catch block of a java service after calling the pub.client:http service?

Comment: Your try/catch block is within the java service or in the flow service that's invoking pub.client.http service ?

Comment: Within the java service so that i get a service exception which wraps a net exception...

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke the `pub.client:http` from within a flow service, you'll notice that it doesn't throw an exception. For example, a "403 Forbidden" error, will not throw an exception. Instead, it will output to the pipeline a header document.

[image]

Within the header document you will find the http status:

[image]

When you invoke `pub.client:http` from within a java service then the invocation is suppose to return an `IData` object. From that object you should be able to extract the status field using `IDataUtil`.

So, when you evaluate that the status is not OK, you can throw a `ServiceException` which will be caught by the flow try/catch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but this seems to be wrong. With your described behavior I would be totally satisfied, but in Webmethods 9.8 you get an exception instead of a 401 status...

Comment: WebMethods 9.5 here. Try doing it in a flow service as described. Use this forbidden url http://www.checkupdown.com/accounts/grpb/B1394343/ .Are you sure you are getting an exception ?

Comment: Will try it again tomorrow.